# Yii ActiveRecord does not populate the parent object

Tags: yii2

I am trying to get an active record by a property.

```
$user = self::find()->where(["username" => $username])->one();
```

When I check the method `one()`, I see, the `BaseActiveRecord::populateRecord($record, $row)` gets the row from the database.

As you see on the picture, the row has retrieved, but for some reason, my object has not populated.

I've tried to add setters for the fields, result is the same.

Can somebody help me with this?

[image]

**EDIT:**

I've checked the `BaseActiveRecord` class:

```
public static function populateRecord($record, $row)
{
    $columns = array_flip($record->attributes());
    foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
        if (isset($columns[$name])) {
            $record->_attributes[$name] = $value;
        } elseif ($record->canSetProperty($name)) {
            $record->$name = $value;
        }
    }
    $record->_oldAttributes = $record->_attributes;
    $record->_related = [];
    $record->_relationsDependencies = [];
}
```

Of course, the `$columns[$name]` has set.

**EDIT2:**

Here is my whole ActiveRecord class:

```
<?php

namespace app\models\database;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Exception;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class Admin extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public int $id = 0;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public string $username = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public string $password = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public string $auth_key = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public string $access_token = '';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName(): string
    {
        return 'admin';
    }

    /**
     * @param int|string $id
     * @return Admin|IdentityInterface|null
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        $user = self::find()->where(["id" => $id])->one();
        if ($user) {
            return null;
        }
        return new static($user);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $token
     * @param null $type
     * @return IdentityInterface|static|null
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        $user = self::find()->where(["accessToken" => $token])->one();
        if ($user) {
            return null;
        }
        return new static($user);
    }

    public static function findByUsername($username): ?Admin
    {
        $user = self::find()->where(["username" => $username])->one();
        if ($user) {
            return null;
        }
        return new static($user);
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey): bool
    {
        return $this->auth_key === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function validatePassword($password): bool
    {
        return $this->password === Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $insert
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function beforeSave($insert): bool
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if ($this->isNewRecord) {
                $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getAccessToken(): string
    {
        return $this->access_token;
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuthKey(): ?string
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Attributes values are inside of `$_attributes` property and attributes are handled as virtual properties in `__get()` and `__set()`. You should remove explicit attributes from your model and `$user->username` should work just fine then.

Comment: Do you mean, remove `public $username;` from the class? Tired it, does not helped.

Comment: Rob006's comment is right. You should add more of your code (model, attempts of reading properties) to your question. There is something wrong with your model or with the way you are accessing properties.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that the `__get()` magic method is overriden without calling the implementation of `__get()` from `yii\db\BaseActiveRecord`.

Comment: @MichalHynčica I've added my whole `Admin` class.

Comment: @vaso123 You still have properties defined in your model, which are conflicting with virtual attributes from AR.

Comment: @rob006 Ok, if I remove them, then the `$user->username` will be there,  but this isn't an elegant design. Can not I properly define the fields of my object?

Comment: Ok, I see how should I use it, I am just wondering. This design is rage against the immutable objects principle, I never use any public field in a symfony project, neither a static call. I am sad now, because i **should** use it. No autocomplete, lot of warning in IDE. Sigh...

Comment: You can use phpDoc's `@property`  to make autocomplete work and deal with warnings in IDE.

Comment: @MichalHynčica thank you.

Comment: @rob006 add it as an answer to allow me to accept it.

Comment: The whole point of Active Record is mutability. If you want immutable objects, you should not use AR in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` stores attributes in private property [`$_attributes`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/03235e6c12010441e360c8e4c336cee0b5cbba5b/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L90) and exposes them as virtual properties via `__get()` and `__set()`. It works as long as you don't define real property with that name (which you did). In that case you either need to remove these properties (for example `public string $username = '';`), or use [`getAttribute()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#getAttribute()-detail) to fetch attribute value (much less convenient):

```php
$username = $user->getAttribute('username');
```